# How to use a windows service as a crash restarter

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, windows-8

I recently built an `.exe` that needs to stay open. (Or re-open after crashed) I have decided to make a watchdog program to restart it when it is closed/crashes. If I can create the watchdog program to work, how would I use a function like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make my watchdog (which would be a windows service) able to start an executable in the session of the user logged on?

**Edit:**

Actually, if they don't do the same thing as a fork bomb, would having two vbs scripts doing something like this work?

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
WshShell.Run "c:\somefolder\script1.vbs", 1, true
Loop
```

along with this script

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
WshShell.Run "c:\somefolder\script2.vbs", 1, true
WshShell.Run "c:\somefolder\program.exe", 1, true
Loop
```

Okay. The two VBS scripts work really well. I have a question about VBS, but I'll ask that as its own question.

Comment: You should consider first learning C++. If you don't know the language you will struggle through every aspect and likely end up producing something that just doesn't work very well at all.

Comment: `I was asking if anyone knows a c++ program that can do what the batch program can` Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If someone could point out where to start on making the C++ version of the batch program, I can do the rest. I have heard that Python is similar to the C programming languages, and I have time to learn.

Comment: @gunr2171 So far, just that batch program, and a bunch of reading on windows services.

Comment: The solution in C# is going to be very different than C++ (I've done it in C#, its not that hard). Which language do you *actually* want?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Well, since the CreateProcessAsUser is in C++, I think it should be in that.

Comment: You can do the same thing in C# with `Process.Start` it just depends on which tech you want to use. If you want C++ though, you should remove the C# tag.

Comment: There is going to be more to it than just calling CreateProcessAsUser if you want the user to see the window (check the remarks section of the MSDN entry).  

An easier and lower-tech solution might be to put your batch file into the user's startup folder.  That will cause it to run when the user logs in.  If you need to watchdog it, you could put your watchdog executable in the user's startup.

Comment: @JMarsch Actually, there is no need for the service to have a GUI. I just need it to start a program like notepad.exe if not already running, and check every 5 seconds or so. I don't mind it being background, as long as the program it opens is _not_ background. (The things I have tried have led to notepad.exe without a GUI and other such things. I just want something that makes that instance of notepad to be visible to the user. The service itself should be invisible)

Comment: @CoilKid Sorry that was what I meant -- if you want the user to see the notepad window, there is more to do.  You see, running a program as a user and running a program inside of an existing session are 2 different things -- just running a program as me just means that it has my security settings, and some of my environment settings, but even if I'm logged in, it won't necessarily run in my session.  (In windows, they call that your Window Station).

Comment: @JMarsch I need to figure out how to make the service watchdog be able to start an `.exe` in the user's desktop. If I can get that working, I can make the watchdog by using Google and reading up on c++. Generally, I'm not worried about crashes. The executable seems to be bug free (so far). I am just looking for a way to make the `.exe` require admin permission to be shut down. (Make it system, make a system watchdog etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also the reason people ask questions like yours is often because they don't like the console window.

This vbs script starts the console window hidden.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

msgbox FormatNumber(WshShell.Run("cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false))
```

Also your batch file consumes much system resources incl battery life.

Try

```
:Start
c:\somefolder\program.exe
Goto Start
```

This starts your program, does nothing till it exits, then starts it.

That can be done in vbscript or vb6 (or vb.net by adding a couple of brackets).

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WshShell.Run "c:\somefolder\program.exe", 1, true
Loop
```

OR this which waits for an event.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

In the run method. 0 is hidden and true/false is wait for program to exit.

---

**EDIT**

The WMI one may look like it's event driven, which it is. But WMI uses polling (appears to be 1 sec). So it has the same resource problems as the first batch file. All you do is move the blame from your program to WMI.

---

**Edit 1**

All my scripts I posted do what you want. You only need 1 script not 2. In the looping ones it waits for program to exit then continues. None of the scripts exit. They just keep waiting until your program stops running, then restarts it and waits till it stops again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of having a service process monitor for your primary application. And if it isn't running, then starts it in the desktop session of the current user.

See this [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx) for some details about doing that.

You will also need to think about what the behavior should be when there isn't somebody logged on, or when multiple people are logged on.

Answer (score 0):

Application Recovery and Restart.

Application Recovery and Restart
Applications have the opportunity to control what actions are taken on their behalf by the system when they fail.

If the application calls the RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback function, the system executes the recovery callback on application failure. The application can attempt to recover documents. If the application has not registered for recovery, the system still attempts to diagnose and report the problem.

If the application calls the RegisterApplicationRestart function, the system restarts the application after the recovery or diagnosis is completed. If the application has not registered for restart, the system closes the application.

From Help.